# Cannot center buttons inside ScrollView properly

Tags: android, scrollview, center, locked

I saw this question asked everywhere but I think each case has its own resolution. What I have is this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/MenuScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and what I pretend is having the `LinearLayout` centered inside the `HorizontalScrollView`. It is centered (I see *halfbutton - button - halfbutton*) but I can't scroll to the first button. Looks like the space occupied by the content hidden to the left is added at the right and some space is added after the `HorizontalScrollView`.
[image]

Is there any solution, even if I have to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, to avoid it just remove

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

from

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="0dp" >
```

You can add a timer while creating the layout view to scroll properly. If you don't add the timer, it won't scroll due to the view not being created. You can't scroll something it can't be seen yet

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //SOME SCROLLING FUNCTION
            }}, 50);
```

Comment: It does but the buttons are not centered inside the `HorizontalScrollView` anymore. By centered I mean 3 to the left and 3 to the right. I would try `ScrollTo` but it doesn't to.

Comment: ScrollTo normally has an issue when you try to scroll before the view is created. Try adding a timer task, I'll add it to the solution